# Can't find Windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: installation, partitioning, dual-boot

I know questions like this have been asked before, but this is a bit different. I told it to install Ubuntu on the Partition that had Windows on it. After that, I couldn't start windows anymore. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have answered it here: http://askubuntu.com/a/150644/68508

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed your question is different. If you **really** installed Ubuntu over your Windows partition then your Windows has been overwritten and is deleted.

In case you had non-backuped data on this partition you may be able to restore them (at least partly) with [data recovery tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery).

Comment: If there is data you want off the former Windows install, STOP USING THE COMPUTER NOW and find another one (at a friends or a library, etc.)  The more you use the computer, the more chance of overwriting stuff.

Comment: If I remember right, this was the problem. Again, if I remember right, I did do a scan and rescue, but it didn't have any of the folder structure what-so-ever, and I don't think I will ever use any of the data (thankfully it was one of those cases).